# Laravel eloquent HasMany error de tipo al incluir una relacion hasMany en el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Tengo un problema con Eloquent al incluir los registros de una relacion uno-a-muchos desde una tabla clientes y otra tabla de creditos. El campo que los relaciona en ambas tablas se llama **idecli** y en ambos casos es del tipo **varchar** en la base de datos.

Tabla de creditos (**tblmca**)

```
CREATE TABLE public.tblmca (
  ide BIGSERIAL,
  idecli VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
...
```

tabla de clientes (**tblcli**)

```
CREATE TABLE public.tblcli (
  idecli VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
...
```

**Loan.php**

```
class Loan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tblmca';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ide';

}
```

**Customer.php**

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tblcli';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idecli';

    public function loans() {
        return $this->hasMany(Loan::class,'idecli','idecli');
    }
}
```

**CustomerController.php**

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
            $customers = Customer::
                with('loans')
                ->paginate(10);
        return $customers;
    }
}
```

Genera dos consultas:

La primera sobre la tabla **tblcli** obteniendo los 10 registros:

```
select * from "tblcli" limit 10 offset 0
```

la cual, al parecer recupera el campo **idecli** como un **integer** y no como una **varchar** (ojo que ese campo solo contiene numeros literalmente).

Basado en esta consulta Eloquent genera una segunda consulta sobre la tabla hija, para obtener los creditos.

```
select * from "tblmca" where "tblmca"."idecli" in (4161524, ...
```

La base de datos se queja porque estoy comparando una cadena con un entero:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  el operador no existe: character varying = integer\nLINE 1: select * from \"tblmca\" where \"tblmca\".\"idecli\" in (4161524, ...\n                                                       ^\nHINT:  Ningún operador coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos. (SQL: select * from \"tblmca\" where \"tblmca\".\"idecli\" in (4161524, 8092485, 13927282, 37651274, 37860273, 41317188, 91498237, 1098609370, 1098659303, 1098696254))"
```

Lo correcto es que la consulta que se genera deberia ser:

```
select * from "tblmca" where "tblmca"."idecli" in ('4161524', ...
```

Como le informo a Eloquent en la relacion **hasMany** que tanto la llave local, como la foranea son del tipo **string**

Answer (score 0):

Laravel eloquent asume que la llave primaria es **numerico**, por cuanto es necesario informarle al modelo que la llave es de tipo **string**

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use EloquentJoin;

    protected $table = 'tblcli';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idecli';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
...
}
```